# prettier line break not accept rules

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I try to change line break with prettier, but **vs code** ignore my settings for this...
I try to put **`line-length: 140`** but nothing happened.

I try this, but without success

```
// edit your tslint.json
"max-line-length": [
     true, 
    { 
        "limit": 140, 
        "ignore-pattern": "^import |^export {(.*?)}" 
    }
],
```

I use

```
prettier: [3.18.0]
VS code: 1.41.1
```

here are my settings

```
{
  "workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs": true,
  "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
  "window.menuBarVisibility": "default",
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
  "files.autoSave": "off",
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "editor.rulers": [
    140
  ],
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 140,
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": false
  },

  "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
  "vsicons.projectDetection.autoReload": true,
  "files.eol": "\n",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "javascript.referencesCodeLens.enabled": true,
  "cSpell.userWords": [
    "dropdown",
    "toastr"
  ],

  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
  "html.format.wrapLineLength": 140,
  "editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
  "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "preserve-aligned",
  "prettier.printWidth": 140
}
```

Is there any another way to get this to work, because prettier always format my components or html file in a strange way...
let's say, 
this

```
languageLocale: [null, [Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(255)]],
```

to this

```
languageLocale: [
        null,
        [Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(255)]
      ],
```

or html

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input class="disabledInput" formControlName="id" matInput/>
</mat-form-field>
```

to this

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input
               class="disabledInput"
               formControlName="id"
               matInput
               />
</mat-form-field>
```

And this is terrible to read if we have multiple input fields

Answer (score 0):

Need to put config to `package.json`

Refered to here https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

```
"prettier":{
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "insertPragma": false,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "jsxSingleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 140,
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "requirePragma": false,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": false,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "useTabs": false,
  "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
  "rangeStart": 0
}
```